# Getting Simply Accounting's MySQL connection information

Tags: mysql

My organisation is using Simply Accounting (S.A.) as the accounting system for a larger project. I see that it's using MySQL as its back-end database. I'd like to scrape some data out of the database directly instead of through S.A.'s interface.

Is there a way I can sniff out the Username and Password that S.A. is using? 
Alternately, how I could I add my own account to the database, and avoid the whole thing altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it... found here [(now broken)](http://www.simplyaccounting.com/community/forums/p/5399/19091.aspx#19091) or [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20090928023248/http://www.simplyaccounting.com/community/forums/p/5399/19091.aspx)

I didn't find out how to sniff the username, but I did find out what it is and the rest of the connection info.

```
connection type: TCP
username:        sysadmin
password:                  ''// <-- default is blank 
database:        simply    
host:            myMachineName
port:            ######    ''// You can get this using the following procedure

1. Open Simply Accounting
2. Go to Help->About Simply Accounting [blah blah blah]
3. Click on "Support Info"
4. look in the top-right corner of the Support Info window, you will see a
   region labelled "Database Engine". The Port is listed at the bottom.
```

Scrape away.

Note, S.A. MUST BE OPEN for you to connect to it.

Comment: In my case I needed to modify sysadmin permissions to allow 3rd party connections.  I was able to do so by logging in as single user mode under the "Edit users..." (Using simply accounting 2011).

Comment: The link to the forum post is broken.  I am trying to fix an issue a broken Simply DB.

Comment: Archive.Org's Wayback Machine is your friend for broken links. 
https://web.archive.org/web/20090928023248/http://www.simplyaccounting.com/community/forums/p/5399/19091.aspx 
I only included the link o credit the original source.

Answer (score 1):

If you can start/stop MySQL server of S.A. system, you can restart it with option --skip-grant-tables, connect with usual mysql client without knowing root password and create necessary users.

Don't forget to restart MySQL again without --skip-grant-tables to close your server from others.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) about adding user accounts to MySQL.  And then you want to add a user and grant them full rights on the S.A. database.